# How can I do a find & replace using PDFSharp?

Tags: c#, replace, pdfsharp

I have a PDF file with 3 static place holders that I need to replace.

The place holders are using the following format:

[item1ToReplace]
[item2ToReplace]
[item3ToRepalce]

So my question is how can I read in the pdf, replace the values, and save a new pdf using PDFSharp, or a simliar opensource library?

Target language is C# on 3.5 framework.

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like the problem has been talked about a little here http://forums.asp.net/t/1408202.aspx

they're using itextsharp http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/ .

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I ended up creating a helper class to write the PDF out line by line. Not the way I was hoping to do it, but it was the faster solution at the time.